# Filter Google Custom Search Engine results by site

Tags: google-custom-search

I have been having issues using the Custom Search Engine API while (trying to) using the functionality of its specific site search.

I have created (using the web console) a CSE and defined it to search in 2 sites:

*.ebay.com
*.amazon.com

First, when searching for the term 'pcrush' (with curl), I receive results from amazon.com and ebay.com domains, as expected. this is ok.

```
curl -X GET 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=<my-key>&cx=<my-cx>&q=pcrush'
```

When I try making the same search but limit the results to be just from a specific site, I still get results from both eay and amazon.

Here, I want to receive only the ebay.com results:

- adding &as_sitesearch=ebay.com
- adding &as_sitesearch=ebay.com&as_dt=i
- adding &as_sitesearch=amazon.com&as_dt=e
- all of the above example, when the domain is *.ebay.com or *.amazon.com

It all still returned results both from ebay.com and amazon.com

- I should mention we are following the API as described [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#WebSearch_Query_Parameter_Definitions).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.